# Install JDK on Linux with .tar.gz archive

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, installation, archive

I'm trying to install the .tar.gz package on my new ubuntu machine.
I'm coming from Windows Environment. Usually after the package have been extracted one can easily call "java -version" on the folder where the binaries are located.

However my archive binaries, which I extracted on a custom folder, are not found when typing

These are my environment variables:

```
franrizz16@sviappmfa01:~/programs/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/franrizz16/programs/java/jdk1.8.0_202
franrizz16@sviappmfa01:~/programs/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/franrizz16/programs/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin
```

when typing "java -version" the output is the following:

> -bash: /home/franrizz16/programs/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java: No such file or directory

but the file actually exists in "bin" folder.

I expected that typing "java -version" would output the jdk version.

This is my ls on $JAVA_HOME/bin folder:
[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the output of `ls /home/franrizz16/programs/java/jdk1.8.0_202/bin`

Comment: Also, are you sure you downloaded the distribution for the correct architecture?

Comment: The output of ls command has been added, and the package downloaded is: jdk-8u202-linux-i586.tar.gz (which is for Linux x86)

Comment: Unless you have a very old machine that's the wrong package. You most probably want the x86_64 version. You *can* run 32-bit software in 64-bit linux but 1) it's not ideal; 2) it requires specific commands to run.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't expect that x64 machines could not run x86 programs without any troubles (On windows is possible without any changes)

Comment: You need to install x86 library support to do that. Why though? And you should be using your package manager to install software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you wrote in your comments, you downloaded the 32-bit version of the jdk. You need to download the 64-bit (x86_64) one.

You mentioned you are accustomed to Windows running both 32-bit and 64-bit programs. While 64-bit versions of Linux can run 32-bit programs just fine, they don't do it out of the box. You'll need to install 32-bit library support. See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12956/how-do-i-run-32-bit-programs-on-a-64-bit-debian-ubuntu) on how to do it.

But unless you have very specific reasons to run 32-bit software on a 64-bit machine, you're better off simply installing the correct version.

(Note, here I'm talking about x86 specifically. I don't know whether ARM or MIPS behave differently regarding 32- vs 64-bit).

Comment: It's not really good practice to download *anything*. The package manager should be used to *install* the correct version

Comment: @g00se unless your distro doesn't provide that specific version (case in point: debian). Otherwise, yes, absolutely.

Comment: Even then, there are better ways: (case in point: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bellsoft.list, Debian, from my own machine *deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.bell-sw.com/ stable main*)

Answer (score 0):

you could extract the source to `/opt` directory.
e.g.:

```bash
sudo tar -xf /location-to-file/jdk1.8.0_202.tar.gz -C /opt
echo "JAVA_PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_202" >> $HOME/.bashrc
echo "PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_PATH/bin" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```

close the terminal and reopen and then try run `java -version` to make sure it work

or you could read the easier way here
https://gist.github.com/filipelenfers/ef3f593deb0751944bb54b744bcac074

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The problem here is that they downloaded the wrong version for their architecture. How dose extracting it somewhere else solve that?

Comment: Okay, my mistakes, I just read whole comment of the thread. He suppose to update the thread to be **SOLVED**

Comment: They couldn't mark it as solved because there were no answers.